# BizTalk build error

Tags: jenkins, biztalk

I'm trying to build a BizTalk application through Jenkins and encountering a weird error. I was able to build the .btdfproj successfully a few days ago. Nothing was changed in the setup project or the server.  I can see the Microsoft.Sdc.Tasks.dll in the location as well.

I'm not sure what is the issue is here. Any ideas?

> error MSB4062: The
>   "Microsoft.Sdc.Tasks.BizTalk2006.Application.Delete" task could not be
>   loaded from the assembly C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\DeploymentFrameworkForBizTalk\5.0\Microsoft.Sdc.Tasks.BizTalk.dll.
>   Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\DeploymentFrameworkForBizTalk\5.0\Microsoft.Sdc.Tasks.BizTalk.dll'
>   or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly
>   and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a
>   public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, that was a silly mistake. Someone moved the jenkins job, one folder up and one step in the job's configuration had the older path hardcoded. I undid the move and it started building successfully. The error was totally misleading though.